# Symfony update managed Entity elsewhere

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity

The usual way [to update an entity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#updating-an-object) is like this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$product = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')->find($id);
$product->setName("New product name!");
$em->flush();
```

Calling persist() is not necessary: since you fetched the $product object from Doctrine, it's already managed.

**But**: what if fetch an entity and then pass it onto a update function, like so:

```
// Somewhere in the application I get the Product entity, call a setter, and want to save the Entity:
$product->setName("A new name!");
$productService->update($product);

// Inside productService:
function update(Product $product) {
    // what to do here to update the entity? Is it still managed?

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $em->persist($product);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Calling persist() would not be necessary if it's still managed, but is it? The code in update(..) does seem to work, but is it the right way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried this at all? You shouldn't need to `persist` it no matter where you do it from as you are passing around the same object, rather than creating a copy on each method call.

Comment: Thnx, I've updated my post with the code I'm using now (which seems to work) but I just wanted to verify this is how Symfony/doctrine works

Comment: I mean have you tried it without the persist?